# Java Card returning 6F00 while installing applet

Tags: applet, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform, jcop

I have a J3H081, SCP 02, T=1, GP 2.2.1, JC 3.0.4 java card and want to install applets onto it.

Unfortunately I get on every *.cap file I tryed error 6F00 (Command aborted - more exact diagnosis not possible (e.g., operating system error)).

I tried the pre-compiled *.cap from here: https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-u2f-javacard, built it myself with JavaCard v3.0.3 SDK, from AppletPlayground
I tried the OpenPGPApplet and YkneoOath. All result in an 6F00 error while installing.

The only applet I was able to install was the pre-compiled AlgTest_v1.7.4_jc222.

Card info:

```
java -jar ../gp.jar --info --debug --verbose
GlobalPlatformPro v0.3.10rc9-0-g53bcab8
Running on Linux 4.10.0-28-generic amd64, Java 1.8.0_171 by Oracle Corporation
# Detected readers from JNA2PCSC
[*] Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00
SCardConnect("Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00", T=*) -> T=1, 3BF81800008131FE450073C8400000900080
SCardBeginTransaction("Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00")
Reader: Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00
ATR: 3BF81800008131FE450073C8400000900080
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3BF81800008131FE450073C8400000900080

A>> T=1 (4+0000) 00A40400 00 
A<< (0018+2) (51ms) 6F108408A000000151000000A5049F6501FF 9000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Auto-detected ISD: A000000151000000
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA9F7F 00 
A<< (0045+2) (24ms) 9F7F2A47906B644700E4D8030063550209109858130000000000000000027B5B32303931300000000000000000 9000
[WARN] GPData - Invalid CPLC date: E4D8
[WARN] GPData - Invalid CPLC date: 5B32
CPLC: ICFabricator=4790
      ICType=6B64
      OperatingSystemID=4700
      OperatingSystemReleaseDate=E4D8 (invalid date format)
      OperatingSystemReleaseLevel=0300
      ICFabricationDate=6355 (2016-12-20)
      ICSerialNumber=02091098
      ICBatchIdentifier=5813
      ICModuleFabricator=0000
      ICModulePackagingDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
      ICCManufacturer=0000
      ICEmbeddingDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
      ICPrePersonalizer=027B
      ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentDate=5B32 (invalid date format)
      ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentID=30393130
      ICPersonalizer=0000
      ICPersonalizationDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
      ICPersonalizationEquipmentID=00000000

***** GET DATA:
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0042 00 
A<< (0000+2) (17ms) 6A88
GET DATA(IIN): not supported: 0x6A88 (Referenced data not found)
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0045 00 
A<< (0000+2) (16ms) 6A88
GET DATA(CIN): not supported: 0x6A88 (Referenced data not found)
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA00C1 00 
A<< (0004+2) (19ms) C1020010 9000
GET DATA(SSC): 0010
***** CARD DATA
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0066 00 
A<< (0080+2) (24ms) 664E734C06072A864886FC6B01600B06092A864886FC6B020202630906072A864886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B040255650E060C2A864886FC6B050601000001660C060A2B060104012A026E0103 9000
Tag 6: 1.2.840.114283.1
-> Global Platform card
Tag 60: 1.2.840.114283.2.2.2
-> GP Version: 2.2
Tag 63: 1.2.840.114283.3
Tag 64: 1.2.840.114283.4.2.85
-> GP SCP02 i=55
Tag 65: 1.2.840.114283.5.6.1.0.0.1
Tag 66: 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.110.1.3
-> JavaCard v3?
***** KEY INFO
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA00E0 00 
A<< (0020+2) (27ms) E012C00401FF8010C00402FF8010C00403FF8010 9000
Version: 255 (0xFF) ID:   1 (0x01) type: DES3 length:  16 
Version: 255 (0xFF) ID:   2 (0x02) type: DES3 length:  16 
Version: 255 (0xFF) ID:   3 (0x03) type: DES3 length:  16 
Key version suggests factory keys
SCardEndTransaction(Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00)
SCardDisconnect("Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00", true)
```

Content of card:

```
java -jar ../gp.jar -l --debug --verbose
GlobalPlatformPro v0.3.10rc9-0-g53bcab8
Running on Linux 4.10.0-28-generic amd64, Java 1.8.0_171 by Oracle Corporation
# Detected readers from JNA2PCSC
[*] Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00
SCardConnect("Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00", T=*) -> T=1, 3BF81800008131FE450073C8400000900080
SCardBeginTransaction("Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00")
Reader: Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00
ATR: 3BF81800008131FE450073C8400000900080
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3BF81800008131FE450073C8400000900080

A>> T=1 (4+0000) 00A40400 00 
A<< (0018+2) (48ms) 6F108408A000000151000000A5049F6501FF 9000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Auto-detected ISD: A000000151000000
Warning: no keys given, using default test key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
A>> T=1 (4+0008) 80500000 08 9EB971B0B997A506 00
A<< (0028+2) (113ms) 00000000000000000000FF02001075FB090C524005ED5FE35EC4870E 9000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Host challenge: 9EB971B0B997A506
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Card challenge: 001075FB090C5240
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Card reports SCP02 with key version 255 (0xFF)
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Will do SCP02 (8)
[DEBUG] PlaintextKeys - Card keys: {MAC=type=RAW bytes=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F, DEK=type=RAW bytes=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F, ENC=type=RAW bytes=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F}
[DEBUG] PlaintextKeys - Session keys: {MAC=type=DES3 bytes=4EBEDA3CFAF1AF9F51E5C5C1A209FA12 kcv=56F2E8, DEK=type=DES3 bytes=3D8EE3E7D528FB11B228B6A2A9E67843 kcv=586B99, ENC=type=DES3 bytes=9DCFBA55D0D2D1F93A76F4E664AC7557 kcv=36ACF2}
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Verified card cryptogram: 05ED5FE35EC4870E
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Calculated host cryptogram: 63BF4653BE559138
A>> T=1 (4+0016) 84820100 10 63BF4653BE559138CA2DEC59F3F525DF
A<< (0000+2) (79ms) 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F28002 0A 4F008AC3124F676735BA 00
A<< (0021+2) (39ms) E3134F08A0000001510000009F700107C5039EFE80 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F24002 0A 4F00B6E52A345E5EDFE1 00
A<< (0000+2) (37ms) 6A88
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F22002 0A 4F002244873B1D1B0175 00
A<< (0172+2) (85ms) E31B4F07A00000015153509F700101CE020202CC08A000000151000000E31E4F0AA0000001644C504B49009F700101CE020100CC08A000000151000000E3234F0FA000000396545300000001000306009F700101CE020100CC08A000000151000000E3234F0FA000000396545300000001000605009F700101CE020100CC08A000000151000000E3234F0FA000000396545300000001000404009F700101CE020100CC08A000000151000000 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21002 0A 4F00712BF00E7238B760 00
A<< (0239+2) (104ms) E3254F07A00000015153509F700101CE0202028408A000000151535041CC08A000000151000000E32B4F0AA0000001644C504B49009F700101CE020100840BA0000001644C504B490001CC08A000000151000000E3594F0FA000000396545300000001000306009F700101CE0201008410A00000039654530000000100030000008410A00000039654530000000100030000108410A0000003965453000000010003000020CC08A000000151000000E3474F0FA000000396545300000001000605009F700101CE0201008410A00000039654530000000100060000008410A0000003965453000000010006000010CC 6310
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21003 0A 4F003843F0BC3CF26677 00
A<< (0064+2) (62ms) 08A000000151000000E3354F0FA000000396545300000001000404009F700101CE0201008410A0000003965453000000010004040000CC08A000000151000000 9000
ISD: A000000151000000 (INITIALIZED)
     Privs:   SecurityDomain, CardLock, CardTerminate, CardReset, CVMManagement, TrustedPath, AuthorizedManagement, TokenVerification, GlobalDelete, GlobalLock, GlobalRegistry, FinalApplication, ReceiptGeneration

PKG: A0000001515350 (LOADED) (|....QSP|)
     Parent:  A000000151000000
     Version: 2.2
     Applet:  A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)

PKG: A0000001644C504B4900 (LOADED) (|....dLPKI.|)
     Parent:  A000000151000000
     Version: 1.0
     Applet:  A0000001644C504B490001 (|....dLPKI..|)

PKG: A00000039654530000000100030600 (LOADED) (|.....TS........|)
     Parent:  A000000151000000
     Version: 1.0
     Applet:  A0000003965453000000010003000000 (|.....TS.........|)
     Applet:  A0000003965453000000010003000010 (|.....TS.........|)
     Applet:  A0000003965453000000010003000020 (|.....TS........ |)

PKG: A00000039654530000000100060500 (LOADED) (|.....TS........|)
     Parent:  A000000151000000
     Version: 1.0
     Applet:  A0000003965453000000010006000000 (|.....TS.........|)
     Applet:  A0000003965453000000010006000010 (|.....TS.........|)

PKG: A00000039654530000000100040400 (LOADED) (|.....TS........|)
     Parent:  A000000151000000
     Version: 1.0
     Applet:  A0000003965453000000010004040000 (|.....TS.........|)

SCardEndTransaction(Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00)
SCardDisconnect("Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00", true)
```

When I try to install OATH:

```
java -jar ../gp.jar -d -v -install OATH.cap 
GlobalPlatformPro v0.3.10rc9-0-g53bcab8
Running on Linux 4.10.0-28-generic amd64, Java 1.8.0_171 by Oracle Corporation
# Detected readers from JNA2PCSC
[*] Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00
SCardConnect("Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00", T=*) -> T=1, 3BF81800008131FE450073C8400000900080
SCardBeginTransaction("Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00")
Reader: Alcor Micro AU9540 00 00
ATR: 3BF81800008131FE450073C8400000900080
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3BF81800008131FE450073C8400000900080

A>> T=1 (4+0000) 00A40400 00 
A<< (0018+2) (34ms) 6F108408A000000151000000A5049F6501FF 9000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Auto-detected ISD: A000000151000000
Warning: no keys given, using default test key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
A>> T=1 (4+0008) 80500000 08 0212B343EC673A6B 00
A<< (0028+2) (114ms) 00000000000000000000FF0200123E6DB216F8D55680B3F7A550C757 9000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Host challenge: 0212B343EC673A6B
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Card challenge: 00123E6DB216F8D5
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Card reports SCP02 with key version 255 (0xFF)
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Will do SCP02 (8)
[DEBUG] PlaintextKeys - Card keys: {MAC=type=RAW bytes=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F, DEK=type=RAW bytes=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F, ENC=type=RAW bytes=404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F}
[DEBUG] PlaintextKeys - Session keys: {MAC=type=DES3 bytes=89D93B2D2D7E7AB95B61F82EDE3975B7 kcv=B98C32, DEK=type=DES3 bytes=F162D1055E932F638893C5BCF9F31D70 kcv=04E63C, ENC=type=DES3 bytes=CB4ED15E982DB16EB630FE9F3E04D665 kcv=C98825}
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Verified card cryptogram: 5680B3F7A550C757
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Calculated host cryptogram: F9A02202A22F47BF
A>> T=1 (4+0016) 84820100 10 F9A02202A22F47BF4DB56FD47F42B8B1
A<< (0000+2) (79ms) 9000
CAP file (v2.1), contains: applets for JavaCard 2.2.2
Package: pkgYkneoOath A0000005272101 v0.0
Import: A0000000620001 v1.0
Import: A0000000620102 v1.3
Import: A0000000620101 v1.3
Applet: A000000527210101
Generated by Sun Microsystems Inc. converter 1.3
On Wed May 16 07:15:59 PDT 2018 with JDK 1.8.0_171 (Oracle Corporation)
Total code size: 4122 bytes (5036 with debug)
SHA256 (code): FA159806A9880A6B687E787890F77FCBAF5A6ED63CD553D20E47CA19BC7CD733
SHA1   (code): 864A34575269AD52BC694D24A185763594C91F9D
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F28002 0A 4F0019A4B5BCFD8D0E2A 00
A<< (0021+2) (39ms) E3134F08A0000001510000009F700107C5039EFE80 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F24002 0A 4F004B9459BB164EFEC9 00
A<< (0000+2) (42ms) 6A88
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F22002 0A 4F0061B9817E563CFF60 00
A<< (0172+2) (75ms) E31B4F07A00000015153509F700101CE020202CC08A000000151000000E31E4F0AA0000001644C504B49009F700101CE020100CC08A000000151000000E3234F0FA000000396545300000001000306009F700101CE020100CC08A000000151000000E3234F0FA000000396545300000001000605009F700101CE020100CC08A000000151000000E3234F0FA000000396545300000001000404009F700101CE020100CC08A000000151000000 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21002 0A 4F002D58C5CF80ACEF82 00
A<< (0239+2) (116ms) E3254F07A00000015153509F700101CE0202028408A000000151535041CC08A000000151000000E32B4F0AA0000001644C504B49009F700101CE020100840BA0000001644C504B490001CC08A000000151000000E3594F0FA000000396545300000001000306009F700101CE0201008410A00000039654530000000100030000008410A00000039654530000000100030000108410A0000003965453000000010003000020CC08A000000151000000E3474F0FA000000396545300000001000605009F700101CE0201008410A00000039654530000000100060000008410A0000003965453000000010006000010CC 6310
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21003 0A 4F0056722CCB8A815B1A 00
A<< (0064+2) (67ms) 08A000000151000000E3354F0FA000000396545300000001000404009F700101CE0201008410A0000003965453000000010004040000CC08A000000151000000 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0028) 84E60200 1C 07A000000527210108A00000015100000000000058BCFCB1F099FA44
A<< (0001+2) (207ms) 00 9000
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
A<< (0001+2) (468ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80001 FF 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
A<< (0001+2) (95ms) 00 9000
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
A<< (0001+2) (98ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80003 FF 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
A<< (0001+2) (96ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80004 FF 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
A<< (0001+2) (98ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80005 FF 1808058D0026871018048D00298711181008900B8712AD11AD120310088B002C188F00193D8C001A8713188F00193D8C001A87147A05308F002F3D8C0030181D0441181D258B00317A0626188B0032980090198B00332D03321A1F5903011079381A1F5903017B0034925B387B0034031A1F7B0034928D001F3B1F7B0034925B41321A1F590301107138AD129229041A1F59030116045B38AD12031A1F16048D001F3B1F16044132AD138B0018602B1A1F5903011074381A1F590301100838AD111A1F10088B002CAD131A1F1008AD0E038B00233B59030819031F8B00357A198B00332D198B00363B03321A052529041A06252905160481BBBFD1CCD35C16
A<< (0001+2) (95ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80006 FF 16058D003729061A04252907AD138B0018601A160710A36A141607076A0FAD100325046A081169828D002716077500F50009FFA1007FFFA20094FFA300B5FFA400CBFFA500EC000100290002003E00030053000400681606610A181A8C0038A800C9116B008D0027A800C01606610A181A8C0039A800B4116B008D0027A800AB1606610A181A8C003AA8009F116B008D0027A80096160611DEAD6B09188C003BA80088116B008D0027A8007F1606610B18AD0F8C003C327071116B008D0027706916046117160560071605046B0E181A1605AD0F8C003D327050116B008D002770481606610C181AAD0F8C003E32703A116B008D002770ACC58C344F680C4A
A<< (0001+2) (96ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80007 FF 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
A<< (0001+2) (96ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80008 FF 8B002329051A031075381A0416055B38AD0E031A0516058D001F3B160505417806250831191E5902012510736A08116A808D002718191E8C0044321E181F8C004641311F610BAD13038B0042A800A4191E590201252904AD14191E16041F04438B00471E1F04434131191E5902012510746A08116A808D002718191E8C0044321E181F8C00464131AD14191E1FAD0E038B002329051E1F4131191E5902012510756A08116A808D002718191E8C0044321E181F8C004641311F16056A08116A808D0027191EAD0E031F8D001C611EAD13280618AD14871318150687141506038B0042AD13048B004270081169848D00277A064408290419582074F67C3AB076
A<< (0001+2) (96ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80009 FF 16045904012510716A08116A808D0027181916048C0044290516041816058C004641290419160416058D00482806150667081169848D0027160416054129041916045904012510746A08116A808D0027181916048C0044290516041816058C00464129040329071E611C15061916041605AD0E038B002329051B1607590701107538701A15061916041605AD0E038B004929051B16075907011076381607181B1607160504418C004A4129071B160759070115068B004B38AD0E031B160716058D002A3B16051816058C00464105417807440829041916045904012510746A08116A808D0027181916045904018C00442905191604AD0E5A89361AE2EE1309
A<< (0001+2) (98ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E8000A FF 0316058D001F3B0329047B0015280615069E00AB15068B00186105A800981B16045904011071381B160459040115068B004C5B38160415061B16048B004D41290403290715068B004E10F05310206B3D1E611E1B16045904011075381506AD0E0316051B160405418B0023290770271B16045904011076381506AD0E0316051B160405418B00492907700B1B16045904011077381B1604590401160704415B381B160459040115068B004B38160416074129041506830C2806A8FF56160478042203317B00152E1B66381B8B00186104702A191E590201107238191E5902011B8B004C04415B38191E5902011B8B004E381E1B191E8B00791A625D7F4ADD8D
A<< (0001+2) (126ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E8000B FF 4D41311B830C2E70C91E7804230831191E5902012510716A08116A808D002718191E8C0044321E181F8C00464131191E1F8D004828041504660A1504038B004270081169848D00277A031203307B00152D1A661A1A8B00186104700C1D1A8B004C10094141301A830C2D70E71D7806250831191E5902012510716A08116A808D002718191E8C0044321E181F8C00464131188C004F1F411009411108006F08116A848D0027191E1F8D004828041504670F8D005028041504191E1F8B00511E1F4131191E5902012510736A08116A808D002718191E8C0044321E181F8C00464131191E5902012529051605100F53046A101605100F53057BDA2F5ADF5F159F
A<< (0001+2) (98ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E8000C FF 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
A<< (0001+2) (102ms) 00 9000
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
A<< (0001+2) (171ms) 00 9000
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
A<< (0001+2) (97ms) 00 9000
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
A<< (0001+2) (94ms) 00 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0182) 84E88010 B6 050A0D070A0F0A040514141111103F08070A0807130404060408040A07071306060405240B1B0C0A0505140C1A34090C090C090E090D0918090D091809080909090404080B03080812060908070C0F15060E070E171A06070B171606070D1606070D0916060817070A0B0C18070A161A180E0C091A0A0D070C190C0B221C241B08150D081E0607080C08080809210607061006090A14060720180E070C20081F0B07062F094809040C154309070CDB5802F6E3CB92AB
A<< (0001+2) (2s5ms) 00 9000
CAP loaded
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F28002 0A 4F00CE1365F547E4B025 00
A<< (0021+2) (39ms) E3134F08A0000001510000009F700107C5039EFE80 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F24002 0A 4F00F8EA3A41D6663EF4 00
A<< (0000+2) (43ms) 6A88
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F22002 0A 4F00ACF0434BA5896E89 00
A<< (0201+2) (83ms) E31B4F07A00000015153509F700101CE020202CC08A000000151000000E31E4F0AA0000001644C504B49009F700101CE020100CC08A000000151000000E3234F0FA000000396545300000001000306009F700101CE020100CC08A000000151000000E3234F0FA000000396545300000001000605009F700101CE020100CC08A000000151000000E3234F0FA000000396545300000001000404009F700101CE020100CC08A000000151000000E31B4F07A00000052721019F700101CE020000CC08A000000151000000 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21002 0A 4F005758A6044FC20332 00
A<< (0239+2) (105ms) E3254F07A00000015153509F700101CE0202028408A000000151535041CC08A000000151000000E32B4F0AA0000001644C504B49009F700101CE020100840BA0000001644C504B490001CC08A000000151000000E3594F0FA000000396545300000001000306009F700101CE0201008410A00000039654530000000100030000008410A00000039654530000000100030000108410A0000003965453000000010003000020CC08A000000151000000E3474F0FA000000396545300000001000605009F700101CE0201008410A00000039654530000000100060000008410A0000003965453000000010006000010CC 6310
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21003 0A 4F004806318F830710EE 00
A<< (0103+2) (80ms) 08A000000151000000E3354F0FA000000396545300000001000404009F700101CE0201008410A0000003965453000000010004040000CC08A000000151000000E3254F07A00000052721019F700101CE0200008408A000000527210101CC08A000000151000000 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0040) 84E60C00 28 07A000000527210108A00000052721010108A000000527210101010002C90000957AA3B988C90CF0
A<< (0000+2) (799ms) 6F00
Install for Install and make selectable failed: 0x6F00
```

After installation:

```
PKG: A0000005272101 (LOADED)
     Parent:  A000000151000000
     Version: 0.0
     Applet:  A000000527210101
```

But I am not able to use it:

```
>> 00A4040008A000000527210101
<< 6A 82 (File not found)
```

Why am I not able to install any applet besides AlgTest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you probably don't have the features necessary for those applets and applet initialization throws an exception which is not handled. This specific case seems to be no support for ECC.

Answer (score 2):

During installation of the applet, some exception has been raised in constructor/install method of class and **because this exception is never catch**. The installer applet (in JCRE) returns **0x6F00** (or sometimes 0x6400).

You best bet to resolve this issue is to apply try-catch at different sections of code and try to install the applet. By this way, you may come to know about the un-supported feature of the applet in the card-OS.