# Why does my JavaCard Applet work on my JAVACOS card but not my NXP J3H145 or ACOSJ card?

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, contactless-smartcard

I have written and successfully installed an apple tonto a JAVACOS smart card.

I can install this applet onto my NXP J3H145 and ACOSJ card, but when I try to interact with it I get the error code 6F00.

Why is this?

I am using JCIDE to develop my applet and Global Platform Pro to install the applet.

Comment: These platforms may not have features required for your applet, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378151/java-card-returning-6f00-while-installing-applet

Comment: Are you using all technologies the card accepts/supports? https://www.smartcardfocus.us/files/J3H145/J3H145_product_briefing.pdf ? Are your byte adresses correct according to the specification of the card? Do you have integration tests to confirm every feature/io port works as intended(sort of a systems check, all systems nominal captain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the cryptographic function being used in the applet was not supported by the NXP J3H145 OR ACOSJ card, but was by the JAVACOS card.

To find out which algorithms are supported on a particular card you can check the specs or use the profiler available here: https://opencryptojc.org/ (scroll down and choose metrics which will take you to this page [https://www.fi.muni.cz/~xsvenda/jcalgtest/](https://www.fi.muni.cz/%7Exsvenda/jcalgtest/) )where you can download the profiler.

There is also a database of algorithms supported by different cards on the site.